# Turn off spellcheck in OneNote 2010

Tags: spell-check, microsoft-onenote-2010

How to disable spellchecker in all OneNote 2010 documents? I want it to be off by default in all my current and future documents/notes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to `File` > `Options` > `Proofing` and un-check the `Check spelling as you type` box

[image: Uncheck combobox]